# Test cafe - Page Object - Consume Modules

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've been working mainly with selenium (java) and espresso as automation tools. I'm pretty new to test cafe and liking it so far. 
I came across this specific situation and was wondering what would be the best way to solve it using javascript or test cafe.

I am using Page Object design on my suite. In addition, I would like those pages to be able to consume many modules that can also be consumed from many other pages.

As an example, let's say I have a Home page that has a Header and Footer modules and I also have a listing page that has a Header, a Footer, and a carousel that shows items (This carrousel also appears on other pages). 
I was thinking of creating something like a generic page but not sure if it was the best solution. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

For generic items, create Page object class separately. For example in your case create page object for header/ footer, carousel area and place them in the generic package for better classification.

Invoke them where ever required (i.e. invoke header/ footer in homepage as well as in listing page).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of doing that... But what I am not completely sure is if I can extend multiple classes from one. For instance, I'll need to extend Header and Footer from Home page.

Comment: You can initialize object for as many classes you wish and use in required class ( i.e. creating Object for header/ footer and etc in homepage class constructor. And if navigation required for specific page class, you can create object on the navigation method for avoiding object allocation at earlier constructor stage).                           
And hope you are using Selenium page factory model.